# equivalent command of net group /domain for linux?

Tags: linux, dns, usergroups

I've been searching for quite a while for this, And couldn't find it anywhere.

Firstly, Is there equivalent command to:

```
wmic computersystem get domain
```

Which return the current user primary domain.

And I've been wondering whether there's an equivalent command of:

```
net group /domain
```

A command that returns all the global groups of user current domain.

So far I've been trying to search in different network files at /etc/, Currently the only relevant file I've found was reslov.conf which hold all the DNS, And it might contain more information than i actually need. [Which means that i'll have to query each domain there and 'ask' whether the user is associated with that domain] is there a way which is more efficient than that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Un*x hostname

```
hostname -f
host.domain

host host.domain
host.domain has address 192.168.1.35
```

See `man host`, `man dig` and `man hostname`. Have also a look at *See also* sections in man pages.

#### Windows `net` command under Linux

You have to install at least `samba-client` package. After installing `samba` suite, you will be able to run linux's `net` command:

```
net help
Usage:
net rpc             Run functions using RPC transport
net rap             Run functions using RAP transport
net ads             Run functions using ADS transport
net file            Functions on remote opened files
net share           Functions on shares
net session         Manage sessions
net server          List servers in workgroup
net domain          List domains/workgroups on network
net printq          Modify printer queue
net user            Manage users
net group           Manage groups
net groupmap        Manage group mappings
net sam             Functions on the SAM database
net validate        Validate username and password
net groupmember     Modify group memberships
net admin           Execute remote command on a remote OS/2 server
net service         List/modify running services
net password        Change user password on target server
...
net help            Print usage information
Valid targets: choose one (none defaults to localhost)
    -S or --server=<server>         server name
    -I or --ipaddress=<ipaddr>      address of target server
    -w or --workgroup=<wg>          target workgroup or domain

Valid miscellaneous options are:
    -p or --port=<port>             connection port on target
    -W or --myworkgroup=<wg>        client workgroup
    -d or --debuglevel=<level>      debug level (0-10)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept of domain you mention is ambiguous.

The equivalent of `wmic computersystem get domain` is `dnsdomainname` .

This isn't the command to return the current user primary domain (Active Directory domain or otherwise).

That command for Active directory domain for a given Unix user mapped with samba is

```
wbinfo --sid-to-fullname `wbinfo --uid-to-sid username` | awk -F "\\" '{print $1}'.
```

Also see the following related [StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398107/how-to-get-the-users-domain-information-in-samba).

The equivalent of `net group /domain` is `net ads group -w <domainname>`, which is provided by Samba. The `net group /domain`  isn't for a current user as you have described it, if you want the command equivalent of your description you will need to add `-U <username>` to the equivalent given.

If you are just looking for a command to get the groups of the current user, then `getent group | grep username` for the unix groups and existing Windows groups to Unix groups as per the Winbind configuration, or

```
wbinfo --user-domgroups `wbinfo --uid-to-sid username`
```

for the global groups of a current user in a domain.